# Cluster Center in Spark Streaming k-means Clustering

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Streaming k-means to cluster some 2-dimensional stream data using the example in

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#streaming-k-means.

code:

```
model = StreamingKMeans(k=5, decayFactor=0.7).setRandomCenters(2, 1.0, 0)
model.trainOn(trainingData)
clust=model.predictOnValues(testData.map(lambda lp: (lp.label, lp.features)))
```

It is working well without error. Now, I need to find and print the cluster center in each batch or over each sliding batch. Considering that the centroids are made with decayFactor of 0.7, how can I find/calculate the cluster centers?

Comment: Once the model is trained you can access the cluster centers via the method `clusterCenters()`

Comment: AttributeError: 'TransformedDStream' object has no attribute 'clusterCenters'
I think streaming kmeans doesnt have any clusterCenters() method.

Comment: Can you give me the output of `model.latestModel().clusterCenters`?

Comment: Yes, it is working, model.latestModel().clusterCenters shows the clusters. Thanks.